# wp_set_object_terms() to update a post taxonomy value

Tags: terms

I need to update the taxonomy value of my post, so i tried with wp_set_object_terms() but it creates me a new value instead.

My taxonomy : 'expediteur'

The taxonomy value ID to be attached: 69

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, '69', 'expediteur');
```

thanks for help

Comment: You need [`wp_update_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/) instead. To update a taxonomy term, you doesn't need to think with the `post_id`.

Comment: and so my post will be saved with taxonomy value passed in wp_update_term()  ? there is no post_id parameter...

Comment: @Pipoo, if you're adding a taxonomy term to the post, try setting the 4th parameter to `true` - `wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, '69', 'expediteur', true );`

Comment: no i don't want to add a new term, only update my post with an exiting term

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. I wasn't referring to *creating a new term*. Just try it out and see if it works.. :)

Comment: thanks , this works : wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'my-existing_slug', 'expediteur');

Comment: Actually, using the term ID also works, but the ID must not be quoted - because `'69'` is a string and seen as a term slug, but `69` (no`'`) is a number and seen as a term ID. Hope that helps.

Comment: you are right , thanks a lot !!!